# Applying class to an element if it has a child with certain class

Tags: css, stylus

is it possible in CSS or Stylus to apply style to an element if it has certain child class?

doing this for example:

```
.par > .chld
    background-color:red
```

Will color the child, but I need to color the parent

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: As @alex mentions, there's no ascending CSS selector. Usually, if you find a need for this, you're going about something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that because CSS can't do that, unfortunately.

CSS has no ascending selectors (yet).

If you look at the [CSS4 working draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational), you can see a `:has()` selector has been proposed.

Comment: What about Stylus? No way?

Comment: @Agzam Stylus can't circumvent CSS' limitations